# Easiest hash function to implement on Qiskit

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit, circuit-construction, grovers-algorithm, cryptography

Trying to build an Oracle circuit for Grover's algorithm that will try to find a desired input in order to get a certain output of a hash function.

Was wondering if there were any 4 or 8 bit hash functions out there or any hash functions that could be easily built into a quantum circuit (obviously building up from classical circuits)

Any help would be great Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this article https://qibo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/hash-grover/README.html - seems like it's exactly what you are looking for.